# What is connection of X (XML) in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

AJAX (which is an acronym for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML), I can understand the Asynchronous JavaScript, but `XML` part drives me nuts!!

Can anyone tell me the connection how it is **Asynchronous** JavaScript and **XML** **(Asynchronous XML)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [introductory article](http://adaptivepath.org/ideas/ajax-new-approach-web-applications/) published in 2005 by Jesse James Garrett from AdaptivePath somehow gave birth to the AJAX acronym. At that time, JSON wasn't yet in the picture and XML dominated the landscape of formats exchanged between browsers, servers and web services (SOAP anyone?).

Aside from that, the underlying browser object used to implement Ajax in the beginning implemented an interface named `IXMLHTTPRequest`, [brought to us by Microsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#History_and_support). Later on, Mozilla provided a similar object called `XMLHttpRequest` which eventually became a de facto standard (glorified by W3C in 2006) for implementing asynchronous communications between browsers and servers.

So, the facts that 1) one of the major interchange formats back then was XML and 2) those payloads were carried around via browser objects called `XmlHttpRequest` are basically the main historical reasons why there's an X in Ajax.